# Debian apt-get broken after trying to install skype

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I tried to install Skype on my x86_64 computer, only to be faced with disaster, I followed the instructions on the Debian website, https://wiki.debian.org/skype for the 64bit instruction set, but after I try to `sudo apt-get -f install` it gives me the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libavcodec56:i386 libavresample2:i386 libavutil54:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libgsm1:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libopus0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtheora0:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx264-142:i386 libxi6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 tcpd
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386
Suggested packages:
  nas:i386 jackd2:i386 opus-tools:i386 speex:i386 nvidia-vdpau-driver:i386
  vdpau-driver:i386 xvba-va-driver:i386
Recommended packages:
  tcpd:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libavcodec56:i386 libavresample2:i386 libavutil54:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libgsm1:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libopus0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtheora0:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx264-142:i386 libxi6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 tcpd
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386
0 upgraded, 32 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
71 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 140769 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaudio2_1.9.4-1+b1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libaudio2:i386 (1.9.4-1+b1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libaudio2_1.9.4-1+b1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libaudio2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libaudio2:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libaudio2_1.9.4-1+b1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And everytime I try to update or install something it warns about libaudio, and I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: see this https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768651#44

Answer (score 3):

you can try by forcing the installation of libaudio2 using the below command.

apt-get install -f -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" libaudio2

Then continue with normal upgrading process.